# Black Screen Issues with RDP from Windows 11 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-11, l2tp

While supporting a network where multiple remote employees connect to their Windows 10 desktops through RDP, I've run into a vexing problem. Several users have reported black screens upon RDP connection, and all of them are on Windows 11. This post serves to document our troubleshooting journey and the temporary fixes we've found.

### The Issue

- **Affected Population**: Remote staff operating on Windows 11.
- **How They Connect**: Via L2TP VPN, followed by RDP to their Windows 10 desktops.
- **What Happens**: A black screen with an active mouse cursor is all they see upon connecting.

### What's Not Broken

- No RDP issues for clients using Windows 10.
- Linux users also report smooth RDP sessions.

### Technical Specifics

- **Port Information**: Port 3389 is open for both UDP and TCP.
- **Protocols**: If UDP is disabled, connecting via TCP shows an unchanging initial desktop frame.

### Troubleshooting Steps

1. **Toggling WDDM**: Ineffective.
2. **Switching RemoteFX On/Off**: Also ineffective.
3. **Reducing Client-Side RDP Resolution**: No change.
4. **Altering Bit Depth**: Inconsequential.
5. **Bitmap Caching Disabled**: No improvement.

### Temporary Solutions

1. **Reverting to Windows 10**: This works but comes with its own set of problems.
2. **Adopting Linux**: This has proven to be an effective and stable solution.
3. **Third-Party RDP Clients**: Tested mRemoteNG; it's not stable although it avoids the black screen issue.

### Additional Points

- The stability of internet connections has been confirmed through continuous Quick Assist sessions.
- We've been compelled to downgrade multiple Windows 11 machines back to Windows 10 due to this issue.

### Final Thoughts

After trying a multitude of fixes, it's becoming increasingly clear that this is likely an unresolved bug affecting RDP between Windows 11 and Windows 10. It's perplexing that this has been an issue for several months without a resolution from Microsoft. We're left with no option but to rely on less-than-perfect workarounds for now.

Comment: Definitely sounds like you've exhausted most options. The issue seems to be Win11 machines being unable to draw the pixel data on screen. I can only think of uninstalling/re-installing the graphics drivers on both sender and receiver test devices and see if that works. Beyond that, it looks like we'd all benefit from finding out what Microsoft Support have to say about this. I'm particularly interested as we're planning to upgrade to Win11 in the next year.

Comment: Also, if you're in a domain environment it's worth testing with user accounts that are part of the Remote Desktop Users Group and the Remote Desktop Services Users Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
On the Windows 11 client, go to services.msc, change the settings for the *Routing and remote access* to *Automatic (Delayed)* and start the service.

Yes, that's on the client connecting the VPN. I don't understand why, but that fixed it for me.

Comment: I don't understand why either, but this did work! I downgraded a Windows 11 client to Window 10, to fix this issue, but I forgot to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS (as a means of preventing the device from automatically upgrading back to Windows 11 | I recall trying to disable Secure Boot, but it was a Microsoft Surface Laptop that hid that option too well). After the auto-upgrade back to Windows 11, RDP would no longer connect to the remote Window 10 workstation. This gave me the opportunity try your suggestion, and it worked. Thank you so much. Your suggestion is the only thing that worked!